# Can we use variable in import or require in Javascript React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, import, require

i am try to use two variable in require and import but they are not working as i expecting

```
class SvgIllustration extends Component {
    render() {
        const { selectedLanguage = "en", svgName } = this.props;
        const location = `../assets/svg/${ selectedLanguage }/${ svgName }.svg`;
        return <SvgCss
            xml={ require( location ) }
        />;
    }

}
```

Error i get:

> error: bundling failed: src\components\svgIllustration.js:
>   src\components\svgIllustration.js:Invalid call at line 10:
>   require(location)

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this :

```
const location = `../assets/svg/${ selectedLanguage }/${ svgName }.svg`;
```

Dynamic imports are not allowed. you need to import location first with proper require like

```
xml={ require( ../assets/svg/english/wow.svg ) }
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thank you,  but my requirement is to use dynamic import, i have found way to work around by not using dynamic import but using dynamic is the requirement =)